# How should I make my proof about the sum of all parts of a number?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, proof-writing

Let me introduce my problem. I'm creating a little enigma for a website in which I want to use a specific thing I called *"part of a number"*.

> **Definition :** The part of a number $N$ (which not begins by a $0$) of $p$ digits $(p>1)$ is any number of maximum $p-1$ digits read from the left to the right in the
>   number $N$.
>
> **Ex :**  If $N=10023$ the set of its parts is
>
> $$\mathcal{P}=\{1,0,0,2,3,10,00,02,23,100,002,023,1002,0023\}$$ It is forbidden to
>   read the number as if it was "cyclic", for example $231$ is not a part
>   of $N$

Now the goal is to calculate the sum of all parts of a number. I decided to use $\sigma$ to be the symbol to mean "part of" so what I am trying to calculate is $$\sum_{i=1}^{\sharp \mathcal{P}} \sigma_i(N)$$

---

So, before to start with a number of $p$ digits I tried to find a pattern for small numbers. I write $N=a_p a_{p-1} \text{...}a_2 a_1$.

I found 
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^{\sharp \mathcal{P}} \sigma_i(a_2 a_1)=1a_2+1a_1 \\
&\sum_{i=1}^{\sharp \mathcal{P}} \sigma_i(a_3 a_2 a_1)=11 a_3 + 12 a_2 +2 a_1\\ 
&\sum_{i=1}^{\sharp \mathcal{P}} \sigma_i(a_4 a_3 a_2 a_1)=111 a_4 + 122 a_3 +23 a_2+3a_1\\ 
\end{align}$$

Now we can conjecture about the formula for a number $N$. We can see before, if $N$ has $4$ digits then after the sign "equal" we can find this order, four numbers $1$, three numbers $2$ and two numbers $3$. And we need to put first and second the concatenation of $p-1$ of these numbers taken in the same order and continue by decreasing by one number each time.

So for $N=a_p a_{p-1} \text{...}a_2 a_1$, the sum of all parts should begin by $p$ numbers $1$ then one number 1 with $p-1$ number $2$ etc ... and then $$\sum_{i=1}^{\sharp \mathcal{P}} \sigma_i(a_p a_{p-1} \text{...}a_2 a_1)=\underbrace{1...1}_{p-1 \text{ times}}a_p + 1\underbrace{2...2}_{p-2 \text{ times}}a_{p-1} + ... +(p-1)a_1$$

---

OK, so I hope there are no typos, **and my question is** how should I do (usage of which notations, how should I organise my work) to make my proof ? Because it looks really weird.

Thank you in advance.

*EDIT :* $p-1$ and $p-2$ in last formula

Comment: Are you only looking to replace the $\underbrace{1...1}_{p-1 \text{ times}}$ notation and siblings?

Comment: @barakmanos well not really I am asking on how I should work to find at the end this wierd formula. When I made my reasoning for a 3-digits numbers for example I wrote sum of the parts = $(a_3+a_2+a_1)*10^0 + (a_3*10^1+a_2*10^0) + (a_2*10^1 + a_1*10^0)$ but if I try it with $p$ digits I will be stuck in a quick time. I know that I'm not really good in calculus but here I think it is particularly weird.